# core class in magento2

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, core

how can we use
`$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');`
`$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');`
`$tableName      = $resource->getTableName('sales/order');`
in magento2?

What is the replacement of core/resource in magento2?
I have tried with `\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface` but its not instantiating in block or model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection is analog for 'core/resource' alias.

Pay attention on:

- M2 don't have separation on read/write connection, so use $resource->getConnection('default');
- M2 don't use aliases for table names, so use $resource->getTableName('sales_order');

Comment: not found any class `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection`

Comment: sorry, for merchant beta is [\Magento\Framework\App\Resource](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Resource.php)

Comment: Please let me know for developer beta

Comment: for dev beta should be same as for merchant, but why you use so old version

Comment: what is the analog for `core/store`

Comment: @prasad-maganti  `store`